# "Computers are as essential as mobile phones for us" or "Computers are as essential for us as mobile phones."

Tags: comparative-constructions

> 1. Computers are as essential as mobile phones for us.
> 2. Computers are as essential for us as mobile phones.

Which place is better for " as essential as" ?
What kind of adverb is "as adjective\adverb  as " in a sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Both are just the rewording of a simile. Both are probably fine, but if you're speaking formally, you may want to consider These edits:

> 1. Computers are as essential as mobile phones **are** for us.
> 2. Computers are as essential for us as mobile phones **are**.

The "ares" are not really necessary, but can help improve clarity.

If you're speaking informally, both of the above work, as well as the two you suggested, but in a casual, everyday experience, I'm guessing the following is most likely to be heard:

> Computers are as important as mobile phones.

"Important" is more likely to be heard in everyday speech, although not as eloquent as "essential," and "for us" is implied in the casual setting. (Unless you're in a discussion about monkeys using smartphones or some such.)